# How to embed YouTube video with no YouTube branding and YouTube design?

Tags: video, youtube, web

How do some sites make a YouTube embed which completely redesigns the youtube embed player. There is no way to identify that the video is from YouTube including the right click inside the player also shows different menu options like that? Can you help me to create one like that?

Answer (score 1):

First off you have to force HTML5 as a technology used by the YouTube loader (if it chooses Flash you wont be able to change the looks.

Then use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, once the embed player has been loaded into the IFrame. A framework like jQuery makes is easy to make something invisible:

```
$('#foobar').css('display','none')
```

You can therefore also change the color of stuff.

Another possibility is that they simply used some smart overlay divs to hide the YouTube stuff.